# $node->type and $node problems

Tags: nodes

The following doesn't work after calling the $node->type. Can someone help?

```
$nid = 0;
$term_1 = "";

if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))){ 
$nid = arg(1);

$node = node_load($nid);

if(true == strpos($node->type,'article'))
{   
    $result = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_tags_test', array('default'));
    $term_name = isset($result['#items'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name) ? $result['#items'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name : ""; 
   }
 }
```

If I take out the inner if-statement, then it works just fine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why you not write if ($node->type == 'article') ???

Comment: where you want put this code? why you are think so compelex? you can write this very simpler.

Comment: zhilevan, this was in the page template. I originally had $node->type == 'article' but it wasn't working for some reason. I don't know if it's a bug in Drupal or something weird with PHP, but it turns out the error was due to having extra returns (e.g. right after the beginning <?php opening).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the zero-based offset of the first occurrence of the test string. So if your string is `article` and the node type is `article`, it will return `0`.

Your `if` statement is basically doing this check:

```
if (true == 0) { ...
```

Since `0` is a boolean `FALSE` in PHP the condition isn't satisfied, and the `if` construct is never entered.

There are a few ways you can change the `if` statement which basically boil down to the same thing:

- `if ($node->type == 'article') {`
- `if (strpos($node->type, 'article') !== FALSE) {`
- `if (strpos($node->type, 'article') === 0) {`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I originally had the first one but it didn't work for some reason. Actually, after removing my if-statement and going back to the original code without it, the old code seemed to have stopped working too. I think I had an extra carriage return in there. I don't know why that would cause the problem??

Comment: Carriage returns wouldn't cause a problem unless they're in the middle of a line of code, I don't think that's the problem :)

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work then. I double-checked everything and it wasn't in the middle of a piece of code. hmm...strange. Oh well, it works now after I removed extra returns!

Answer (score 1):

current strpos return 0 (this is FALSE)

change

```
true == strpos($node->type,'article'
```

to

```
$node->type == 'article'
```